# Asynchronous communication with .net web services using non .net clients - What are the options?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, cross-platform

I am currently investigating the possibilities of creating a .net based web service that can be consumed by both .net as well as non .net clients. I'm particularly looking for an asynchronous communication model using which a client can receive periodic responses(like publish subscribe) from the server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**ASP.net Web API** RESTful web services would be the best route for you to take. It has an asynchronous communication model and also can push to multiple clients. Since it's just a RESTful web service, it's cross platform and virtually any client can consume it.

Answer (score 0):

When you need asynchronous push to  clients then it has to be with Signal R only. This applicable for website, but need to check for webservice/webapi.